# What is clock frequency used for?

Tags: sampling

What is clock frequency used for? for example, a 64MHz microcontroller is used for sampling with a rate of 256 Hz. Why?   I think we can use a simpler one with lower clock frequency?

Answer (score 1):

The MCU clock of 64 MHz is used to run the MCU core and peripherals at that rate.

It may not relate in any way if you want to take samples of something at 256 Hz with it and maybe a slower MCU clock could be used, but it depends if it can do the necessary other processing at slower rate or not.

Answer (score 1):

Each sample will require multiple clock cycles depending on your ADC.
For example, an STM32 requires from 2.5 to 12.5 clock cycles depending on the resolution.

Furthermore, depending on your application, each sample will require some processing which may be much longer than the sampling itself. It is important to have some headroom between each sample.

Likely, 256 Hz Ts will not require a 64MHz clock but the MCU could still have interesting features. You can get a reasonably performant MCU with high maximum frequency, and run it slower without "wasting" it.